# Where not exists in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-3

I want to select all rows from my table except for one, so I added a condition where not exists, but I had an error saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '') '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)"

here is my code :

```
$query = 'select * from etudiant where NOT EXISTS (select * from etudiant where matricule ='.$new_matricule') ';
                $exec = $this->db->query($query);
```

Canyou tell me please what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error **Add a dot**

```
$query = 'select * from etudiant where NOT EXISTS (select * from etudiant where matricule ='.$new_matricule.') ';
```

Comment: I didn't notice that sorry and thank you